# Sorting objects in a recursive generic data structure

Tags: java, sorting, generics, tree

I have a generic tree class in which each tree node holds some data. Each piece of data has one attribute of the type String. I want to sort each tree node's children alphabetically by this attribute.

The Tree class:

```
public class Tree<T>{
    public T data;
    public List<Tree<T>> children = new ArrayList<Tree<T>>();
}
```

Note that the tree's children are of type Tree!

An example actual type parameter for the Tree class is the following:

```
public class DataItem{
    public String name;
}
```

My idea is to extend the Tree class with a sort() method and use a Comparator like the following but I am stuck at the comparison function:

```
public class Tree<T>{
    public T data;
    public List<Tree<T>> children = new ArrayList<Tree<T>>();

    public void sort(){
        Collections.sort(this.children,
            new Comparator<Tree<T>>(){
                @Override
                public int compare(Tree<T> objectA, Tree<T> objectB){
                    //I am stuck here!
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        );
        for(Tree<T> child: this.children){
            child.sort();
        }
    }
}
```

I have different ideas to solve this problem:

- Use reflection to acces the objects' attributes and compare them.
- Implement the interface Comparable in DataItem.
- Use a new interface to acces the objects' attribute for comparison:

  ```
  public interface GetComparisonAttribute {
      public String getComparisonAttribute();
  }

  public class DataItem implements GetComparisonAttribute{
      public String name;

      @Override
      public String GetComparisonAttribute(){
          return this.name;
      }
  }

  //the comparison function inside Tree<T>.sort():
  public int compare(Tree<T> objectA, Tree<T> objectB){
      return objectA.data.getComparisonAttribute()
          .compareToIgnoreCase(objectB.data.getComparisonAttribute());
  }
  ```

What is the right or best thing to do? Are there any other ways?

It may be important to be able to specify the sorting attribute.

I think it would be nice to use Collections.sort() directly on a Tree but implementing it in this recursive data structure really confuses me. A downside of doing it this way is that I cannot specify the sorting attribute.

Comment: I've only glanced over your code, so I may have missed something obvious, but what is your data structure doing that you couldn't keep your `children` in a `SortedSet` instead?

Comment: The data structure I provided here is just a minimal example. It has a lot more methods for traversal and other fancy stuff but they are not important for the problem. Generic data structures are an interesting topic for me so I want this to work. I don't think a SortedSet or TreeSet can store data in every node but just in its leaves.

Comment: Keeping children in a SortedSet does not really solve the problem. For this to work Tree<T> has to implement Comparable but the comparison depends on the Tree<T>'s data attribute. Hmmmm, now I just think defining the data structure as "Tree<T extends Comparable> extends Comparable" solves a part of the problem but it still will not let me specify the sorting attribute for T dynamically.

Comment: Why don't you add bounds to the type parameter - `T extends DataItem`, if you want to allow that specific type of parameters in your `Tree`? In that case, you will be able to access attributes of `DataItem`.

Comment: @RohitJain The Tree hast to work with objects of arbitrary type!

Comment: @EightBitBoy No, you can instantiate both `TreeSet` and `ConcurrentSkipListSet` with an explicit comparator instead of having a `Comparable` element type (or to override the natural ordering). If you can clearly express the ordering you want of those `Tree` objects (which really probably ought to be called `Node` in standard tree terminology), then you can put it into a `Comparator` without cluttering up your API.

Comment: @chrylis I thought about your solution and I think it is the right thing to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void sort(final Comparator<? super T> dataComparator)
    {
        Collections.sort(this.children,
            new Comparator<Tree<T>>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(Tree<T> treeA, Tree<T> treeB)
                {
                    return dataComparator.compare(treeA.getData(), treeB.getData());
                }
            }
        );
        for(Tree<T> child: this.children)
        {
            child.sort(dataComparator);
        }
    }


void test()
{
    Tree<DataItem> tree = new Tree<>();

    tree.sort(new Comparator<DataItem>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(DataItem dataA, DataItem dataB)
        {
            return dataA.getName().compareTo(dataB.getName());
        }
    });

}
```

In java8, this can be simplified as

```
    public void sort(final Comparator<? super T> dataComparator)
    {
        Collections.sort(this.children, 
            Comparator.comparing(Tree::getData, dataComparator));

        for(Tree<T> child: this.children)
        {
            child.sort(dataComparator);
        }
    }


void test()
{
    Tree<DataItem> tree = new Tree<>();

    tree.sort( Comparator.comparing(DataItem::getName) );
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Tree<T> {
    public T data;
    public List<Tree<T>> children = new ArrayList<Tree<T>>();
    private Class<T> type;

    public Tree(Class<T> t) {
        type = t;
    }

    public void sort(){
        Collections.sort(this.children,
            new Comparator<Tree<T>>(){
                @Override
                public int compare(Tree<T> objectA, Tree<T> objectB){
                if (type==DataItem.class)
                   {
                    DataItem diA = (DataItem) (objectA.data);
                    DataItem diB = (DataItem) (objectB.data);

                    return diA.name.compareTo(diB.name);
                    }
                  else
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();

                }
            }
        );
        for(Tree<T> child: this.children){
            child.sort();
        }
    }

}
```

You should pass the type T of the class Tree when you create it. Then you can downcast to `DataItem` and sort the list according to the filed you like. You can check of course also against other type parameters aside from `DataItem`.

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient. If I wanted to use Tree<T> with other types I would have to change the code of Tree<T>!

Comment: If you do not want sorting with other data types then it is sufficient and when you try to sort them, it will throw an Exception. If you want sorting though, you should do the same process in sort() method for other data types

Comment: I reviewed your solution and I like it! It definitely helped me with the problem!